# Why doesn't this readlines() code work in pythonfiddle?

Tags: python

I had to do some quick and dirty text parsing today, and wanted to use it as an opportunity to get some exposure to Python.  So I fired up pythonfiddle.com and concocted this:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://xkcd.com/color/rgb.txt', timeout = 2)
lines = response.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

But it's printing every character on its own line:

```
#

L
i
c
...
```

After a half hour of head-scratching and trying different variations on the same theme, I finally downloaded a real Python shell and ran it locally - where it behaved as intended.

Is there something subtle going on here I'm unaware of that explains why it didn't work the first go 'round?  (e.g. syntax subtleties, version / environment differences, etc). Or is the pythonfiddle implementation broken?  In that case, can anyone recommend a better online fiddler (that doesn't require signup)?

I also noticed other problems with the online tool, e.g. this doesn't compile:

```
import urllib2
for line in urllib2.urlopen('http://xkcd.com/color/rgb.txt', timeout = 2).readlines():
    print line.strip()
```

and it gets easily confused about spaces / tabs.

Comment: What happens when you use `response.read().splitlines(True)`? I suspect that the restricted environment severely limits URL retrieval speeds.

Comment: Note that questions about the pythonfiddle.com service are best directed to them; we can't really help here as we don't know what they are running or how Python is restricted (and it *will* be restricted).

Comment: Ah, the site doesn't use cloud computing, it uses [empythoned](https://github.com/replit/empythoned), so this isn't a *CPython* interpreter, but a different (and flawed) implementation of Python.

Comment: Why the desire for an online fiddler rather than just run python in a shell on your local machine? Do have download/install limitations?

Comment: @jwpfox: Purely convenience.  All I really wanted was the least-friction, fastest way to do a one-time scrape & parse.  Fiddlers are handy for quick tidbits of code when you jump around between machines without tooling installed.

Comment: It might be faster overall to just install python and run it on your machine. Or not, up to you, obviously. Good luck regardless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Python Fiddle FAQ](http://pythonfiddle.com/about/faq/), the site uses the [Empythoned interpreter](https://github.com/replit/empythoned), a translation of the CPython 2.7.2 codebase to Javascript via the [Emscripten cross-compiler](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten).

As the Empythoned project page notes:

> The project is in its infancy. Right now the core interpreter works very well, but many of the libraries either don't work at all or contain various bugs.

As such, there are going to be differences between what a natively compiled CPython interpreter and standard library achieves and what works on Pythonfiddle.com.

In other words: *Here be dragons!*

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I didn't realize they were actually running my code on the client side.  In fact, given the lag time between hitting Run and seeing results, I assumed it was going back to their servers and running a sandboxed executable.  Now I realize that's just the Javascript compiler doing its thing.